# can I run Kila linux on a Vm inside Tails? If so, how?

Tags: tails

I am using tails on a usb and trying to get Oracle's Virtual Box to open inside of tails to run Kali Linux. Can this be done?

Comment: first of all tell me 'is virtualbox supported in TAILS? if yes it is possible provided your pc has at least 4 gb RAM

Answer (score 0):

Maybe but it's not officially supported, see the documentation on [Additional Software](https://tails.boum.org/doc/advanced_topics/additional_software/index.en.html).